# Tekton pipeline cannot create file in the workspace directory unless running as root

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

I want to create a file in the workspace directory. But I can only do that if I run as root with

```
securityContext:
       runAsUser: 0
```

if I leave it blank or want to run as user 1001 it gives me touch: cannot touch '/workspace/workspace_folder/test.txt': Permission denied
It seems like when the workspace directory gets created it is owned by user 99

## Steps to Reproduce the Problem

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: echo-hello-world
spec:
  steps:
    - name: echo
      image: ubuntu
      script: |
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "Current user is"
        whoami
        ls -l
        echo "creating a file in the workspace"
        touch /workspace/workspace_folder/test.txt
      # securityContext:
      #   runAsUser: 0
  workspaces:
  - name: task-workspace
    description: |
      The folder where we write the message to. If no workspace
      is provided then the message will not be written.
    mountPath: /workspace/workspace_folder
---

apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: echo-pipeline
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: pipeline-workspace
  tasks:
    - name: echo-task
      taskRef:
        name: echo-hello-world
      workspaces:
        - name: task-workspace
          workspace: pipeline-workspace
---
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: echo-pipelinerun-6
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: echo-pipeline
  workspaces:
    - name: pipeline-workspace
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi
```

## Output when I run the above pipeline

```
Current user is
1000840000
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 99 99 4096 May 18 01:48 workspace_folder
creating a file in the workspace
touch: cannot touch '/workspace/workspace_folder/test.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: This error can also occur when `volumeClaimTemplate`s  `accessModes` is not chosen correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by design.  If I recall correctly, any container in Kubernetes will run without root privileges if a proper [security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) is not defined. Since the Tekton tasks are also just pods, they will likely be composed with a least privileged security context.  You should be able to verify that in the Tekton-pipelines' source.

If you really need a special workspace volume, I guess you could enable the `disable-working-directory-overwrite` feature-flag [here](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/docs/install.md#customizing-basic-execution-parameters). And either change the working directory in your task spec or use a custom pod spec?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach securityContext to your pipelineRun

```
podTemplate:
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 65532
```

and final YAML for pipelineRun should be like this:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: echo-pipelinerun-6
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: echo-pipeline
  podTemplate:
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 65532 
  workspaces:
    - name: pipeline-workspace
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi
```